# Mysql intended parent child select view

Tags: php, mysql, treeview, parent-child

I am having table parent child id like below

```
id    name     parent_id
1    parent       0 
2    child-1      1
3    child-1      1 
4    parent2      0
5    child-1      1
6    child-2      4
```

I need to get the result as bellow.

```
  parent
    #child-1
    #child-1
    #child-1
  parent2
    #child-2
```

Is this possible to do in single query ?

Comment: This isn't really something you do in MySQL; it's something you handle in the output.  What are you using to output the mysql query?  If you are doing this in the mysql command line only, then what you have is about as good as it gets.  But if you can use something else (bash, PHP, Java, C, etc), then you need to let us know what language you are using to make the MySQL call

Comment: I using php, I can't write two queries because my pagination will suffer.

Comment: @diEcho : I tried with order by, That doesn't help. Because i need to list all child under(next) to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this will work for you, but you haven't given us much to go off of:

In MySQL: `SELECT ... ORDER BY parent_id`

In PHP (this part is pseudo-code(ish)):

```
if($parent_id==0) {
    //is a parent; no indent
} else {
    //not a parent; do the indent
}
```

Comment: I need to list all child under(next) to the parent

Comment: @gowri: you really aren't telling us much.  What do your MySQL tables look like? What are the queries you are using? What have you tried?

Comment: I already gave the table in structure with sample data in my question. What i tried that's in your answer "SELECT ... ORDER BY parent_id". What else i need to give ?

Comment: What is parent_id? Is that a foreign key to another table? If it's just an integer, what does that value mean? What is name? Is that a varchar()? What are the possible values? How is the data being inserted into the database? Why did you choose the table structure the way you did? Have you thought about changing the table structure to make query easier (eg, a sort column)? Have you thought about breaking the parents and children up into separate tables and doing an inner join?